# Ajax form calling without file select in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, upload

I'm using CodeIgniter. I'm using ajax form to upload images. My Main code is,

```
<div id="new_photo">
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/upload1','id="my_new"');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" id="new_photo_upload" name="new_photo_upload" />    
</form>
</div>
```

And my Script is,

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#my_new').ajaxForm(function() { 
            var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: baseurl+"upload/new_photo",
                   success: function( r ) {
                     $('#new_photo').html( r );
                   },
                   error: function(){
                        location.reload( true );
                    }
                });
        }); 
    }); 

</script>
```

Here, if I upload image and click `upload`, it's uploading via ajax and loading **upload/new_photo** as correctly.

But Problem is, without image select if I click upload button, it's loading upload/new_photo. I dont want this. If i choose any image, then only it's submit.

Help Me...

Comment: You could just do a jQuery event on a button and stop the default action with preventDefault, check if a file is selected and continue the script appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the file input:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" />
```

Changes in the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#my_new').ajaxForm(function() { 
        var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: baseurl+"upload/new_photo",
               beforeSubmit: function() {
                    if( $("#userfile").val() == "" ){
                        alert( 'Please select a file to upload!' );
                        return false;
                    }
               },
               success: function( r ) {
                 $('#new_photo').html( r );
               },
               error: function(){
                    location.reload( true );
                }
            });
    }); 
});
```

Look for `beforeSubmit` which validates the input.